# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: EJB not bound

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I have created a sample EJB module for a dynamic web project.But I'm getting EJB not bound when I try to access the Servlet which uses a EJB.

```
package com.za.tutorial;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;     
@Stateless
public class ZASessionBean implements ZASessionBeanLocal {
public String demoSessionBean(){
    return "demoSessionBean";
}
}


package com.za.tutorial;
import javax.ejb.Local;
@Local
public interface ZASessionBeanLocal {
    public String demoSessionBean();
}
```

I have created a dynamic web project and I'm using the above EJB in Servlet as follows.

```
    package com.za.tutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class ZaServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public ZaServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@EJB(mappedName="ZASessionBean/local")
ZASessionBeanLocal objZASessionBean;
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("#ZaServlet#start");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println(objZASessionBean.demoSessionBean());
    System.out.println("#ZaServlet#end");
}



}
```

I created a Ear with the EJB and the web project then deployed in JBoss 5. Post deployment I can see my EJB  is deployed in server console.

> ```
>     ZEN_EAR/ZASessionBean/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
>     ZEN_EAR/ZASessionBean/local-com.za.tutorial.ZASessionBeanLocal - EJB3.x
>     Local Business Interface
> ```

But still when I access my servlet as follows

> http://localhost:8099/ZEN_web/ZaServlet

I get the EJB not bound exception as follows.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ZASessionBean not bound
org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:396)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:726)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1346)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
org.jboss.ejb3.JndiUtil.lookup(JndiUtil.java:44)
org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.lookup(JndiPropertyInjector.java:75   )
org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.inject(JndiPropertyInjector.java:99    )
...........
```

[image]

Comment: I tried adding jboss.xml with following content.
`<jboss>
     <entity>
        <ejb-name>ZASessionBean</ejb-name>
        <local-jndi-name>ZASessionBean</local-jndi-name>
    </entity>
</jboss>`
I placed it in deploy folder of jboss..But still facing the same issue..Somebody please help

Comment: Issue is resolved by adding jboss.xml in ejb module..

Comment: Watch the server log for any errors during deployment. If you can see logs about your bean being deployed without errors, try to use the jmx console to see what is registered with JNDI.